# Reactive field using jquery plugins

Tags: jquery-ui, voltrb

I'm migrating an app from rails to volt which uses some jquery plugins.

As example, one of them is http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

I'm using opal-jquery inside action_ready to call the plugin, and visually it works. However internally it hides the original input and uses .val() to set the value for that input once the slider gets moved by the user. The problem is that even that the input is declared with a reactive field as its value, once jquery changes its value, the variable stays the same instead of syncing with the input value

this problem could be reproduced by creating a input like

```
<input type="text" value={{_value}} id="example"/> <p>{{_value}}</p>
```

and in the console do something like

```
$('#example').val('only the visual will change')
```

the same thing would apply for other plugins like jquery.ui sortable in which the callback would populate a field from the model with a index value.

is there a way to make legacy plugins that change values work with voltrb?

Comment: You do that after document ready?